# Make Google Bot detect AJAX contents

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, modal-dialog, seo

I'm developing a site (not mine) and I encountered a big trouble!
In this website I've got some modals that will open after a user clicks on a product, but I need to do so Google Bot detects these modals like pages. When a modal opens, a JS Function adds a # parameter to the URL like "#abc=modal_one". 
I want that in Google Result appears this page as "www.test.com/page.php?#abc=modal_one". I've tried (and I'm trying) to render the page like Google Bot in Google Search Console, but GSC opens only the page and not the modal. I also added a ES6 (JS) code that just edits the page title when the modal is showing to the user (after user clicks to open the modal) but nothing, Google does not detect the page title set after the page is loaded.

If you can't understand something just tell me and I will try to explain my trouble newly.

Thanks in advance to all the StackOverflow community :)

Comment: spiders don't execute JS code. if you want the bot to spider something, it has to be present in whatever's served up by the raw url.

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting the various pages to a dynamic sitemap that Google can read.

View the  [Categorize parameters with the URL Parameters tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en) page for more information.

Comment: Do you think that Google Bot detects the hash variables in the sitemap? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Yes it can and you can help it understand these values.  I have updated my answer to help provide context

Comment: Thank you very much! Tomorrow I'll tell you if it's working or not! :)